# Selenium's HTML Driver not using jQuery form submission event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, selenium, scalatest

Using Selenium and Scalatest, having tested with Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and the default as values for drivers:

I have a form called `form`. It has `onSubmit = 'return false;'`
There is a separate event handler defined in some JavaScript file that gets attached.

I have a field in that form called `field`, and a button called `button`.

When I type things in to the field by hand, and click on `button`, everything works as expected.

When I run this, nothing happens:

```
click on id ("field")
enter("searchTerm")
submit
```

It seems that the submission occurs, and `field`'s value is set back to "".

However, the (seperate) jQuery event handler for the form submission does not fire.

Comment: I'm not familiar with scalatest, but I know that Selenium has a couple different ways of typing and clicking within elements.  Sometimes one way doesn't work depending on the rendered html.  The `OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions` is an alternate class in Selenium in case this is related.  Maybe that helps...if not then someone who has used scalatest would need to weigh in.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure the clicking / interaction part is working okay. In particular, the example they provide that searches via google seems to work fine. I think the problem here is there interaction between jQuery, the form's onSubmit, and selenium. Thanks anyway

Comment: What is the jQuery event triggered by?  page submit?

Comment: Form submission yeah. Clarified in the comments

Comment: Ok, so the issue is the javascript isn't firing.  The only way around this that I have found is to mimic the user action via hardware commands(i.e. move mouse, depress mouse, press enter key, etc...)  The Actions class can do that.  Otherwise it's really hard to determine without having access to the html/javascript for debugging.  The event is bound to something that you need to trigger.  It could be "submit", but that could be a browser submission, which might implement differently in different browser versions/types.  Could you provide the html code of the page with javascript event in it?

Comment: I can't really provide the html, and I think it'd be a lot of work to strip it down to something sufficiently well redacted. It seems that I'm putting selenium testing on hold for now anyway, but thanks for the help